# Why is my class destructor called in immediately?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a very simple class which notifies parent thread when a function in thread is complete. The problem is when instantiate it, constructor is called and then immediately the destructor is called. Here is the class:

```
AutoNotify::AutoNotify(HWND hWnd)
{
    m_hWnd = hWnd;

    ::PostMessage( m_hWnd, IDM_THREAD_STARTED, 0 , 0 );
}

AutoNotify::~AutoNotify(void)
{
    ::PostMessage( m_hWnd, IDM_THREAD_FINISHED, 0 , 0 );
}
```

Here is how I am using this class in another class.

```
UINT CTestDlg::ThreadProc( LPVOID lpVoid)
{
    int result = false;

    CTestDlg *dlg = (CTestDlg *) lpVoid;

    AutoNotify( dlg->m_hWnd );

    if ( (result = dlg->LongFunction()) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
        return result;

    // more stuff

    return TRUE;
}
```

When I step through the debugger, it calls the `AutoNotify` constructor and then immediately its destructor. I figured maybe because of some compiler optimization because the class is empty!? Than I declare its only member variable `m_hWnd` as volatile but still no use. Anyone why is the destructor called in immediately?

Comment: If you don't name the `AutoNotify` object (or bind it to a `const&`), it doesn't survive the `;` that follows it.

Comment: There is no instance of `AutoNotify`.  To say it another way, the local version lasts until the semi-colon is reached on the line that "calls" the constructor.

Comment: `AutoNotify variable_name( dlg->m_hWnd );` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The destructor is called right away because this line

```
AutoNotify( dlg->m_hWnd );
```

creates a temporary object that gets deleted right away.

This line creates a non-temporary object:

```
AutoNotify guard( dlg->m_hWnd );
```

Now the destructor will be called only when the `guard` object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

```
AutoNotify(dlg->m_hWnd);
```

That is a call to your constructor. It creates a temporary object which is immediately destroyed.  You would typically write:

```
AutoNotify a(dlg->m_hWnd);
```

Now it's a named object and will survive until the end of the function.